# Android: Scaling According to Screen Size

Tags: java, android, screen

I'm building a game (similar to *ye olde bricke breakerr* but a fair bit different) in which **everything** ranging from the brick size to the brick spacing to the paddle size to the paddle positioning to the text display has to be dependent on the screen dimensions of the user.

I'm aware of 2 techniques of doing this:

1) Creating a few generic layouts that the program can select based on dimensions
2) Scaling everything by multiplying by USER_SCREEN_AREA/MY_SCREEN_AREA

Obviously, both these methods are rather difficult to implement. What I'm asking is if there is a simpler way to do this... If there isn't, do tell me so as well so I may go and implement the 2nd option which seems better to me..

Comment: I'd like to know why the question has been downvoted... Is my language not clear? Have I formatted it poorly? Please do tell me so that I may correct it... Simply downvoting isn't going to help but explaining the reason would certainly..

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you looking for-

```
//using 'getsize' for custom resolution  
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: No, that's not what I need... I know how to get size using displayMetrics.. I need to scale using them efficiently...